# A mysterious blank line come from an \hskip?

Tags: macros

I use a very complicated `.sty` file. The main purpose of this `.sty` is to enable a special inline box in which texts can be typeset in a very special way. There is no problem inside the box. The `.sty` provides two macros which can be customized by users (like me) which is placed before and after the box. I define these two macros as two `\hskip`s. Everything works well except when the inline box starts at the beginning of a line inside a paragraph, where one additional blank line exists.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{CJKutf8,CJKvert}
\usepackage[papersize={294pt,363pt},total={229.9pt,299pt},centering]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=12pt

\usepackage{pdflscape}\PLS@Rotate{90}
\usepackage{gezhu}%https://code.google.com/p/gezhu/
\let\gezhu@debugbox\gezhu@fbox
\everygezhu={\linespread{0.83}\footnotesize\renewcommand\CJKglue{\hskip 3pt}}
\beforegezhu={\hskip 2.5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\aftergezhu={\hskip 2.5pt plus 2pt minus 0pt}

\def\CJKglue{\hskip 1pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

% Note:
% 230pt = 10pt*21 (characters) + 1pt* 20 (CJKglues)
% In order to make all characters 'fit the grid', 
% text inside the box is 8pt per character, 3pt per CJKglue
% total space around a box is 4pt so as to make characters 'fit the grid',
% but (for some unknown reason) additional 0.5pt is needed on each end.
% ccccccccccgccccccccccgccccccccccgcccccccccc
% ccccccccccggccccccccgggccccccccggcccccccccc
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
\begin{withgezhu}
\leavevmode
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一二三|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}一二三進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一二三|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}二三進行文字測試\par

\clearpage
\beforegezhu={}
\aftergezhu={}
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一二三|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}一二三進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一二三|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}進行文字測試\par
進行文字測試七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一|{朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝朝落}二三進行文字測試\par

\end{withgezhu}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

There are four paragraphs on each page in this MWE. In page 1, the first three paragraphs are good (because the characters 'fit the grid'), but the last one is bad because (1) characters following the box do not 'fit the grid', and more importantly (2) a mysterious blank line from nowhere appears unexpectedly before the box.

Can anybody help fix (1) and (2), please?

Comment: I don't have all the styles to compile, but perhaps might you need a leading `\leavevmode` as the leading element of `\beforegezhu`? Just a guess.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\hskip` starts horizontal mode by itself.

Answer (score 2):

I can't read the script but the additional hspace is adding an extra line breaking place which is confusing the boxing code and forcing two linebreaks. You can stop that with and additional `\nobreak` which I think fixes things here although if you want to allow this space to be dropped at a line break this may need adjusting

```
\beforegezhu={\leavevmode\nobreak\hskip 2.5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
              %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]